# Get Configurable Product options, Price And Add to cart Button On Related Product Section

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2.6, related-products

How to get Configurable Products `options`, `price` on related products sections. Also, put `add to cart` button on each product. right now related products show only the price `as low as` but want to add customer can also see configurable options and add cart button click then product should be added to cart without going to the product detail page.

can any help me?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**`Magento Version: 2.2.6`**

Comment: Can you please add more details to question ?

Comment: @Vivek please see edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create same controller as default addToCart controller.

```
public function execute()
    {
        $currentStore = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $baseUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl();

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();


        $option=array();

        foreach($post as $key => $val) { 


            if($key =='p_id' || $key =='qty' || $key == 'customoption_id' || $key == 'product-custom-option')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else{

                $option[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

       $productid = $post['p_id'];

        $_product = $this->_productRepositoryInterface->getById($productid);

        if ($_product->hasOptions()){    

            $options = $_product->getOptions();
            $customoptions = array();
            $customoptions[$post['customoption_id']] = $post['product-custom-option'];

            $params = array (
                'product' => $_product->getId(),
                'qty' => $post['qty'],
                'price' => $_product->getPrice(),
                'options' => $customoptions,
                'super_attribute'=>$option

            );

        }else{

            $params = array (
                'product' => $_product->getId(),
                'qty' => $post['qty'],
                'price' => $_product->getPrice(),
                'super_attribute'=>$option

            );

        }



       $this->_cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
       $this->_cart->save();
       $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("You added ".$_product->getName()." to your shopping cart."));
       //$this->_redirect('checkout/cart/index'); 
    }
```